# Web App Authentication

Tags: security, soap, php

I'm working on a simple PHP web app to pull some data from our Salesforce to an external database for use in a website. I am a novice with a lot of stuff here but my primary question is regarding authentication.

Correction:
This is the method being used.

```
define("USERNAME", "MyUsername");
define("PASSWORD", "MyPassword");
define("SECURITY_TOKEN", "MyToken");

require_once ('soapclient/SforcePartnerClient.php');

$mySforceConnection = new SforcePartnerClient();
$mySforceConnection->createConnection("soapclient/partner.wsdl.xml");
$mySforceConnection->login(USERNAME, PASSWORD.SECURITY_TOKEN);
```

Clearly I do not want hard coded authentication details in the script. I don't have any knowledge or experience with any of the Authentication methods mentioned (Kerberos, Active Directory, RADIUS, or LDAP).

My question is, what is best practice in a PHP SOAP security and how would I implement it in this scenario.

Thanks

Comment: Are you using single sign on? If not, that code probably isn't for you. You probably mean to take a look the PHP Toolkit, use PHP's SOAP classes directly, or look into leveraging OAuth.

Comment: I just realized this isn't really what I'm using. The method I am using is this. http://pastebin.com/riiKfRj3

Is that a safe approach running on our webserver?

Comment: I added an answer, but this is really better suited on SE; you're just asking about how to keep some general form of authentication secure.

Answer (score 1):

You can store the credentials wherever you would like in PHP, so long as they are secure. Here's some possible solutions:

1. Use a configuration file, and store the data there. Make sure that .htaccess disallows access to the file.
2. Use a database file, and store the data there. Make sure the database file is secure.
3. Use a PHP "options" include. You can usually build a front-end to regenerate the options when saving.
4. Use the web-server OAuth flow, and simply store the refresh token. Store the token itself in any previously mentioned place.

In any case, make sure your server is secure if you store the configuration there, or make sure your database is secure if you store it there. And remember to set proper file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

For any server app, **ALWAYS** store credentials in config (environmental variable, database, etc.).  If you use source control, doing this is an easy way to expose sensitive client details.

As to how to authenticate a server app (always the same user effectively, as opposed to logging in on behalf of users), using OAuth tends to be the quickest since so many frameworks allow you to plugin the OAuth details and just forget about authentication.

Doing OAuth with server apps is kind of weird, since there isn't a good point where you want to "login".  I wouldn't begin to call it a best practice, but I found one convenient way is to setup a connected app for your application, and then hack the webservice flow to get the access token, refresh token, and instance URL needed to support automatically refreshing your access token when it expires.

The hack basically starts the web flow process, then prints the next URL to a console.  Copy and paste to your browser and log in.  With a bad callback URL nothing happens next, just copy and paste the code from the browser and pass it back into your script to get the rest of the details then add to your config.